# Error with randint and iterative loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

i'm  a beginner in python and I am coding a multiplicator challenge in terminal. I need to call the function randint in order to ask random questions about multiplication tables. The problem is that in my iterative loop, the number printed is always the same, it generates a random one but it is the same in every loop, that's a big problem for me, here's my code

```
from random import *

nombreQuestions = int(input("How many questions ? : "))
score = 0
choixTable= int(input("On which number do you want to get asked on ? : "))
multi=(randint(1,10))

for nombreQuestions in range(nombreQuestions):
    question=str(choixTable)+" x "+str(multi)+" = "
    reponse = int(input(question))

    if reponse == choixTable*multi:
       print("Well played")
    else:
       print("Wrong !")
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Compute `multi`  in the loop!

Comment: what do you mean by computing multi in the loop ? Thank you

Comment: `multi` is assigned a value before the loop starts, and it never changes after that.  So of course the printed value is the same every time.

Comment: so how could I fix that

Comment: Move the line of code `multi=(randint(1,10))` to be inside the loop, so it picks a new value each time, just as @MikaelÖhman said.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a score system in python in a multiplication challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73999992/how-to-make-a-score-system-in-python-in-a-multiplication-challenge)

Answer (score 0):

You only call `randint` at the start at line 6 where it is set once before you enter the loop
This means that each iteraction uses the same value
To fix this you need to set `multi` inside the loop (instead of outside)

```py
from random import *

nombreQuestions = int(input("How many questions ? : "))
score = 0
choixTable= int(input("On which number do you want to get asked on ? : "))

for nombreQuestions in range(nombreQuestions):
    multi=(randint(1,10)) # multi is now set every loop
    question=str(choixTable)+" x "+str(multi)+" = "
    reponse = int(input(question))

    if reponse == choixTable*multi:
       print("Well played")
    else:
       print("Wrong !")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `multi=...` in the loop so it will execute on every loop Iteration.

```
from random import *

nombreQuestions = int(input("How many questions ? : "))
score = 0
choixTable= int(input("On which number do you want to get asked on ? : "))


for nombreQuestions in range(nombreQuestions):
    multi=(randint(1,10))
    question=str(choixTable)+" x "+str(multi)+" = "
    reponse = int(input(question))

    if reponse == choixTable*multi:
       print("Well played")
    else:
       print("Wrong !")
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, you all helped me to fix my problem !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a random number each time then you need to call the randint() method inside the loop not outside.

Which mean this line `multi=(randint(1,10))` should be used inside for loop.

Just like this,

```py
from random import *

nombreQuestions = int(input("How many questions ? : "))
score = 0
choixTable= int(input("On which number do you want to get asked on ? : "))

for nombreQuestions in range(nombreQuestions):
    multi = randint(1,10)
    question=str(choixTable)+" x "+str(multi)+" = "
    reponse = int(input(question))

    if reponse == choixTable*multi:
       print("Well played")
    else:
       print("Wrong !")
```

One thing more, specifying the name of the function in the import statement is more preferred i.e., instead of importing like `from random import *` use `from random import randint`

Comment: The last one gives you an error `NameError: multi not defined` as OP used it on line `if reponse == choixTable*multi:`.

Comment: Wops I didn't saw the second use of multi, removing it.