# How to make a score system in python in a multiplication challenge

Tags: python

I am doing a multiplication challenge and I don't have any idea of how making a score system + a percentage of success, here is my code :

```
from random import *

tableRevision1 = int(input("Quelle première table de multiplication réviser ? :"))
tableRevision2 = int(input("Quelle deuxième table de multiplication réviser ? :"))
nombreQuestions = int(input("Combien de questions ? : "))

print("Révision des tables de", tableRevision1, "à", tableRevision2, "-", "Nombre de questions :", nombreQuestions)

for nombreQuestions in range(nombreQuestions):
        multi=randint(tableRevision1,tableRevision2)
        multi2=randint(1, 10)
        question=str(multi)+" x "+str(multi2)+" = "
        reponse = int(input(question))
        score = 0
        

        if reponse == multi*multi2:
           print("Bien joué !")
           score = score + 1
        else:
           print("Loupé ! La bonne réponse est :", multi*multi2)
           score = score + 0
        

print("Votre score est : ", score)
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you share with us what is wrong/not working with the code you have written?

Comment: The score printed at the end is always 1, even if I score more than one

Comment: But I am not sure what multiplication challenge is. Can you describe that in the question? You can do that using the `Edit` option.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73999220/error-with-randint-and-iterative-loop-in-python/73999274#73999274
Do you happen to be doing the same challange as this person (both new contributor, both posted within same day)

Comment: that's it, I created a new account because I have to do it urgently and I can't allow myself to wait another 2 days to ask another question

Comment: You should probably delete the other question and get your accounts merged .-.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 1):

Some refactoring and editing

```
from random import *

tableRevision1 = int(input('Quelle première table de multiplication réviser ? :'))
tableRevision2 = int(input('Quelle deuxième table de multiplication réviser ? :'))
nombreQuestions = int(input('Combien de questions ? : '))

print('Révision des tables de', tableRevision1, 'à', tableRevision2, '-', 'Nombre de questions :', nombreQuestions)

score = 0

for nombreQuestions in range(nombreQuestions):
    multi = randint(tableRevision1, tableRevision2)
    multi2 = randint(1, 10)
    question = str(multi) + ' x ' + str(multi2) + ' = '
    reponse = int(input(question))

    if reponse == multi * multi2:
        print('Bien joué !')
        score += 1
    else:
        print('Loupé ! La bonne réponse est :', multi * multi2)

print(f'Votre score est : {score}, {round((score/(nombreQuestions+1))*100, 1)}%')
```